# CMake message not printing in correct order

Tags: cmake

I know the build philosophy of CMake is "dependency" based and not necessarily in the order of how tasks are noted down in the CMake list.

But when it comes to `message(STATUS ...)` I need them to display in order, otherwise they don't make sense.

Can I somehow tell CMake to run this sequentially?

Example:

```
  message(STATUS "[LOG] COMPILER_PREFIX         =${COMPILER_PREFIX}")
  message(STATUS "[LOG] CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR        =${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "[LOG] CMAKE_C_COMPILER        =${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
  message(STATUS "[LOG] CMAKE_C_FLAGS           =${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
  message(STATUS "[LOG] CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE =${CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE}")
  message(STATUS "[LOG] CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  =${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
  message(STATUS "[LOG] CMAKE_AR                =${CMAKE_AR}")

  message(STATUS "[LOG] Definitions: ")
  get_directory_property(defs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
  foreach (def ${defs})
    message([STATUS] "  -D${def}")
  endforeach ()

  get_property(dirs TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
  message(STATUS "[LOG] Includes: ")
  foreach (dir ${dirs})
    message([STATUS] "  ${dir}")
  endforeach ()

  get_property(libs TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARIES)
  message(STATUS "[LOG] Libraries:")
  foreach (libs ${libs})
    message([STATUS] "  ${libs}")
  endforeach ()
```

The prints as follows:

```
[STATUS]  -DDUMMY
[STATUS]  -D__SL__
[STATUS]  -DMCU
-- [LOG] COMPILER_PREFIX         =
-- [LOG] CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR        = /home/dummy/workspace/project
-- [LOG] CMAKE_C_COMPILER        = gcc
[STATUS]  /home/dummy/workspace/project/inc
-- [LOG] CMAKE_C_FLAGS           =-std=gnu11 -Wextra -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter
[STATUS]  -lgcc
[STATUS]  -lc
[STATUS]  -lgcc
[STATUS]  -lc
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mixing stdout and stderr outputs and will not print "in order".

From the [CMake documentation for v3.25](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/command/message.html#:%7E:text=The%20CMake%20command%2Dline%20tool%20displays%20STATUS%20to%20TRACE%20messages%20on%20stdout%20with%20the%20message%20preceded%20by%20two%20hyphens%20and%20a%20space.%20All%20other%20message%20types%20are%20sent%20to%20stderr%20and%20are%20not%20prefixed%20with%20hyphens.):

> The CMake command-line tool displays STATUS to TRACE messages on stdout with the message preceded by two hyphens and a space. All other message types are sent to stderr and are not prefixed with hyphens.

So when using `message([<mode>] "message text" ...)` choose a single mode instead of mixing them.

Answer (score 1):

> can i somehow tell cmake to run this sequentially?

Either set cmake to be line buffered on both standard streams with `stdbuf`.

Or use `STATUS` for all messages or do not use `STATUS` for all messages from cmake. With your use case you could just `message("-- [LOG] something something")`.